# Mac OS Cocoa: Draw a simple pixel on a canvas

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, pixel, nsimageview

I wish I would find an answer for this. I have searched and searched and couldn't the right answer. Here is my situation:

In a Mac OS Cocoa Application, I want to draw a pixel (actually a few pixels) onto a dedicated area on my application window. I figured, it would be nicer to have a `NSImageView` placed there (I did so with IB and connected the outlet to my app delegate) and draw on that instead of my `NSWindow`.

How in the world can I do that? Mac OS seems to offer `NSBezierPath` as the most basic drawing tool — is that true? This is completely shocking to me. I come from a long history of Windows programming and drawing a pixel onto a canvas is the most simple thing, typically.

I do not want to use OpenGL and I am not sure to what extent Quartz is involved in this.

All I want is some help on how I can pull off this pseudocode in real Objective-C/Cocoa:

```
imageObj.drawPixel(10,10,blackColor);
```

I would love to hear your answers on this and I am sure this will help a lot of people starting with Cocoa.

Thanks!

Answer (score -11, accepted):

NSBezierPath is the only tool available in Cocoa for drawing most primitive shapes, and for many complex shapes.
Detail description you can find here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-BBCHFJJG
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming_Mac_OS_X_with_Cocoa_for_Beginners/Graphics_-_Drawing_with_Quartz

Answer (score 14):

What you are asking for is either of these two methods:

[NSBitmapRep setColor:atX:y:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000347-BBCBEJED) Changes the color of the pixel at the specified coordinates.

[NSBitmapRep setPixel:atX:y:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000347-CJBHBDJI) Sets the receiver's pixel at the specified coordinates to the specified raw pixel values.

Note that these aren't available on iOS. On iOS, it appears that the way to do this is to create a raw buffer of pixel data for a given colorspace (likely RGB), fill that with color data (write a little setPixel method to do this) and then call CGImageCreate() like so:

```
    //Create a raw buffer to hold pixel data which we will fill algorithmically
    NSInteger width = theWidthYouWant;
    NSInteger height = theHeightYouWant;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    UInt8 *data = (UInt8*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(UInt8));

    //Fill pixel buffer with color data
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {

            //Here I'm just filling every pixel with red
            float red   = 1.0f;
            float green = 0.0f;
            float blue  = 0.0f;
            float alpha = 1.0f;

            int index = 4*(i+j*width);
            data[index]  =255*red;
            data[++index]=255*green;
            data[++index]=255*blue;
            data[++index]=255*alpha;

        }
    }

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,

                            provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    //Clean up
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    // Don't forget to free(data) when you are done with the CGImage
```

Lastly, you might be wanting to manipulate pixels in an image you've already loaded into a CGImage. There is sample code for doing that in an Apple Technical Q&A titled [QA1509 Getting the pixel data from a CGImage object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html).

Answer (score 9):

Cocoa's low-level drawing API is Core Graphics (Quartz). You obtain a drawing context and issue commands to draw onto that context. The API is designed to be device-independent (you use the same commands to draw onto the screen as you would to draw onto paper, when printing). Therefore, there are no commands for filling in individual pixels, because there's no such thing as a pixel on paper. Even on the screen, your view may have been transformed in some way so that a single point doesn't map to a single device pixel.

If you want to draw a single pixel, you need to specify a rectangle that is the size of a single pixel, then fill it in. For the pixel at (x,y), you would want a rectangle with origin of (x-0.5,y-0.5) and a size of (1,1).

You can do that with NSBezierPath, or you can get a Core Graphics context (CGContextRef) from `[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]` and use functions like `CGContextFillRect()`.

This obviously won't be very fast if you are drawing a lot of pixels; that's not what the API is designed for. If that's what you need to do, consider creating a buffer with `malloc` and writing your pixel data to that, then using Core Graphics to convert it into a CGImageRef, which can be drawn to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

For drawing pixels as you describe, there's no need to create a path or resort to the Quartz 2D or OpenGL API.

See `NSRectFill()` and related functions like `NSRectFillList()` and `NSRectFillUsingOperation()`.

If you're drawing a lot of individual pixels, `NSRectFillList()` is about as fast as you can do it without resorting to rolling your own image buffers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to draw pixels on OS X:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                             initWithFocusedViewRect:dirtyRect];

    for (int x = 0; x < [rep pixelsWide]; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < [rep pixelsHigh]; y++) {
            NSUInteger pixel[4] = { 0, 255, 0, 255 };
            [rep setPixel:pixel atX:x y:y];
        }
    }

    [rep drawInRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but Quartz has the ability to fill rectangles:

```
void CGContextFillRect (CGContextRef c, CGRect rect);
```

Comment: Or from within drawRect: or a lockFocus block you can directly use NSFillRect without obtaining a CGContextRef

Answer (score 0):

I found your question here a bit late because I have the same problem. Perhaps Apples developer documentation can help you here. I have not tested it myself, but take a look at this document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html

Roughly in the center of the document you will find the section "Creating a Bitmap". It tells you different ways of creating pixel data.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CMKViewController: NSViewController {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         let testIV = TestImageView(image: NSImage(named: "test.png")!)
         // testIV.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100)
          self.view.addSubview(testIV)
          testIV.myPixels = [CGPoint(x:10,y:10)]

    }


}

class TestImageView:NSImageView{

    var myPixels:[CGPoint] = []

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        guard let context: CGContext = NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext else {
            consolePrint("Cannot get graphics context")
            return
        }

        // Fill background to white
        context.setFillColor(.white)
        context.fill(bounds)
        context.setFillColor(NSColor.red.cgColor)


        // Draw pixels
        context.fillPixels(myPixels)


    }
}



extension CGContext {

    func fillPixels(_ pixels: [CGPoint]) {
        var size:CGSize?
        if Screen.retinaScale > 1{
            size = CGSize(width: 1.5, height: 1.5)
        }else{
            size = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        }

        for pixel in pixels{
          fill(CGRect(origin: pixel, size: size!))
        }
    }

    func fill(_ pixel: CGPoint) {
        fill(CGRect(origin: pixel, size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)))
    }
}
```